# Add entire row to DataTable at once using list

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I just want to add List as a DataTable entire row. here is the code which I have tried.

```
private static DataTable _table = new DataTable();

List<string> tempList = new List<string>();

// tempList = {"A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6"}

_table.Rows.Add(tempList);
```

Expected output:

```
      col1|col2 |col3 |col4  |col5| col6
      ----+-----+-----+------+----+--
row1   A1 |  A2 | A3  |  A4  | A5 |  A6
```

However this is not working for me. It will insert data collection to first column.

Actual output:

```
      col1      |col2 |col3 |col4  |col5| col6
      ----------+-----+-----+------+----+--
row1   A1,A2,A3.|     |     |      |    |
```

Please help me to Add entire row using list. thank you

Comment: Have you defined some columns on the DataTable?

Comment: Yes. However tempList.ToArray() is the solution. :0

Comment: ideally you need to do both otherwise you can run into problems :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`DataRowCollection.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) Method expects `Object[]`, so you should probably try:

```
_table.Rows.Add(tempList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 6):

`Rows.Add()` accepts parms[], you can achieve it by converting your `list` into an array.

```
_table.Rows.Add(tempList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add();
        dt.Columns.Add();
        dt.Columns.Add();
        List<string> tempList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
        dt.Rows.Add(tempList.ToArray<string>());
```